# Errors using antd layout component

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to use the layout component from antd. However, I am getting this error message:

```
react.development.js:1618 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at Object.useContext (react.development.js:1618:1)
    at Space (index.js:32:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
useContext @ react.development.js:1618
Space @ index.js:32
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25850
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25750
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <Space> component:

    at Space (http://localhost:3000/black-dashboard-react/static/js/bundle.js:98111:62)
    at Home
    at Route (http://localhost:3000/black-dashboard-react/static/js/bundle.js:76119:29)
    at Switch (http://localhost:3000/black-dashboard-react/static/js/bundle.js:76290:29)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/black-dashboard-react/static/js/bundle.js:75801:30)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/black-dashboard-react/static/js/bundle.js:75458:35)
    at BackgroundColorWrapper (http://localhost:3000/black-dashboard-react/static/js/bundle.js:31:66)
    at ThemeContextWrapper (http://localhost:3000/black-dashboard-react/static/js/bundle.js:2094:66)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

Here is my code:

```
const headerStyle = {
  textAlign: 'center',
  color: '#fff',
  height: 64,
  paddingInline: 50,
  lineHeight: '64px',
  backgroundColor: '#7dbcea',
};
const contentStyle = {
  textAlign: 'center',
  minHeight: 120,
  lineHeight: '120px',
  color: '#fff',
  backgroundColor: '#108ee9',
};
const footerStyle = {
  textAlign: 'center',
  color: '#fff',
  backgroundColor: '#7dbcea',
};
function Home () {
  return(
    <>
        <Space
            direction="vertical"
            style={{
                width: '100%',
            }}
            size={[0, 48]}
        >
            <Layout>
                <Header style={headerStyle}>Hello</Header>
                <Content style={contentStyle}>Content</Content>
                <Footer style={footerStyle}>Footer</Footer>
            </Layout>
        </Space>
    </>
  )
};
```

Comment: What react version?

Comment: The error says: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'use context'), which an error due to context somewhere in your code

Comment: @ColinHale 18.1